# Getting Error _Conda stopped Working while installing anaconda on Windows 7

Tags: installation, anaconda

I am new to python, I am trying to install Anaconda.
While Installation I am Getting Error _Conda.exe stopped working.
Please Help me With this.
Thanks in Advance.

I did some searches on google regarding this problem,but not getting Exact solution for this.I did uninstalled all my previous python software. Also tried by Deleting Existing Path= in Environment Variables also turned off antivirus and windows defender while installation but none of this solved my problem.

Here is the Error Details

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: _conda.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5b8e98f9
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18247
  Fault Module Timestamp:   521eaf24
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000027689
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 9fdb
  Additional Information 2: 9fdba2a63f4c2dea094e8a8465242f54
  Additional Information 3: ed92
  Additional Information 4: ed92830c2b0ac5dd397a2c4181ba244e
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the error pop-up `conda.exe stopped working` while installing Anaconda 3 (2020.02.0.0) in Windows 8.1 and this is what worked for me:

1. Go to `My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables` and search if there are related user environment variables from previous Conda or other Python packages installations:

   - Variables `PYTHONHOME` or even a `PYTHONPATH` may have been created by any Python distribution.
   - Variables starting by `CONDA_*` (for example `CONDA_DEBUG`) created in previous installation tries.
2. **Delete this user environment variables**. If you are not sure about this step, note the variables you delete in order to be able to set them again later if this does not work.
3. Temporarily disable your antivirus during installation (this is recommended in Anaconda documentation).
4. Start your installation again.

Answer (score 0):

This Error occurred to me while installing "Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86",
my short answer is to ***install "[VS C++ Redist](https://www.itechtics.com/microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-versions-direct-download-links/)"***, I installed version 2019 and it worked fine for me and solved the problem.

.

***Here is how I came to that conclusion:***

I tried to reproduce the problem by executing the same command the installer executed to generate the same error, first I used windows Task Manager to find the command arguments passed to "_conda.exe", Then I started CMD and executed the following line:

```
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\_conda.exe" constructor --prefix "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3" --extract-conda-pkgs
```

This generated an error regarding a DLL file "api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll" that is usually included with the C++ runtimes.

ps. I usually use [Sereby's AiO Runtimes](https://www.sereby.org/site/All%20in%20One%20Runtimes&lang=en) to install all runtimes at once!